# SSRS 14 - Background Colour Expression Error

Tags: vba, reporting-services, expression

I've a Matrix in SQL Server Reporting Services with some calculations over a column that only have this results `T`, `F`  or `N/A`.

What I'm trying to do is:

- If the column don't have any result `T` or `F` the colour should be "Gray"
- Else `count("T")/Count("T" U "F")` and if this results is `> 0.5` then "Green" else "Red".

I've this code:

```
=IIF(Sum(IIF(Fields!Indicator_P3.Value = "T" Or Fields!Indicator_P3.Value = "F", 1, 0)) = 0 ,
"DimGray" , 
IIF( Sum(IIF(Fields!Indicator_P3.Value = "T", 1, 0)) / 
    Sum(IIF(Fields!Indicator_P3.Value = "T" Or Fields!Indicator_P3.Value = "F")) > 0.5, "Green" ,"Red" ) )
```

But when I execute the report I'm getting this issue:

```
A expressão BackgroundColor para caixa de texto 'Textbox40' contém um erro: [BC30455] Argument not specified for parameter 'FalsePart' of 'Public Function IIf(Expression As Boolean, TruePart As Object, FalsePart As Object) As Object'.
```

What I'm doying wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Sum(IIF(Fields!Indicator_P3.Value = "T" Or Fields!Indicator_P3.Value = "F")) . What's the Then else values here? I think that's your problem.

Comment: IF I only have "N/A" in the column I want to put DimGray (Basically in the operation that you indicate I'm trying to see if I have any results <> from N/A)
ELSE I want to calculate that operation

Comment: What I'm saying is in the above iff statement you forgot to put the then and else values in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of your IIF statements are not correct. Like Snowlockk mentioned,

```
SUM(IIF(Fields!Indicator_P3.Value = "T" Or Fields!Indicator_P3.Value = "F"))
```

This IIF statement does not have a `true` or `false` value. My guess is, your parenthesis is not closed correctly. Which would mean, you are computing `SUM(GREEN)` for true and `SUM(RED)` for false; which does not make a whole lot of sense. You need to add 2 integer values for true and false conditions in that IIF statement.